# Week Over Week In PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate Week Over Week Impressions for this year vs. last year but below DAX gives a completely blank measure.

Please note I am using a filter for dates between from 'Calendar'[Date] filed.

Can someone help to rectify this?

```
WoW Imp = 
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Date]))
VAR CurrentWeekNum = WEEKNUM(SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Date]))
return
CALCULATE(
    [Total Impressions],
    FILTER(ALL('Reporting Dashboard_Digital'),
    'Reporting Dashboard_Digital'[Year] = CurrentYear-1 &&
     WEEKNUM('Reporting Dashboard_Digital'[Week Start Date]) = CurrentWeekNum))
```

Thanks
Prem

Answer (score 0):

When using SELECTEDVALUE for slicer, `Between` style does not work. Use `Vertical list` style, then measure works